# Status in txResHandler is not reset on second call

Tags: polkadot-js

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)    

const txResHandler = ( status, events, dispatchError, setSubmitting) => {
        setSubmitting(true)
        if (dispatchError) {
          setStatus(null)
          if (dispatchError.isModule) {
            // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
            const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule)
            const { docs, name, section } = decoded
    
            console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`)
            setStatus(name)
            setSubmitting(false)
          } else {
            console.log(dispatchError.toString())
          }
        } else if (status.isFinalized) {
          setStatus(` Finalized. Block hash: ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`)
    
          setSubmitting(false)
        }
      }
```

If previous transaction gives an error `setStatus(name)` in if (dispatchError.isModule) block, then the status/name remains same in the next transaction till `status.isFinalized`, it's not reset to null. How can I remove the previous status?

```
 setStatus('Sending...')    
 const txExecute = api.tx.election.submitCandidacy(...opts)    
  const unsub = await txExecute
              .signAndSend(...fromAcct, ({ status, events, dispatchError }) => {
                txResHandler(
                  status,
                  events,
                  dispatchError,
                  actions.setSubmitting
                )
              })
              .catch(txErrHandler)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a general React question, not really related to the libraries. With that said, ensure that you clear the state when making the call so you don't carry old states around.

Options are -

- you can do it on calling, e.g. explicitly clear the state before making calls
- in your callback, since you are adjusting the status (and we know error is the end of it all), do `setStatus(null)` along `setSubmitting(true)` (this may have other effects in your code, but is an idea)

Comment: I am clearing the state before making calls by setting setStatus("Sending.."), still I get the problem.